# What's the effect of preserve option in fileutils::cp method

Tags: ruby

[FileUtils doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.5/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp) says

> The options parameter is a hash of options, taken from the list :force, :noop, :preserve, and :verbose. :noop means that no changes are made. The other two are obvious.

But I don't understand the effect of `:preserve` option.
In `cp` method, if this option is true, it'll call `copy_metadata` method. What will it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comment of `copy_entry`, which is called from `cp` method:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_1/lib/fileutils.rb#L452

> If +preserve+ is true, this method preserves owner, group, and
>   modified time.  Permissions are copied regardless +preserve+.

And actually `copy_metadata`, which is called from `copy_entry`, is calling `lstat` to acquire the `uid`, `gid`, `atime`, `mtime` from copy source file, and appling it to copy destination using `File.chown` and `File.utime`.

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_1/lib/fileutils.rb#L1399

```
def copy_metadata(path)
  st = lstat()
  if !st.symlink?
    File.utime st.atime, st.mtime, path
  end
  begin
    if st.symlink?
      begin
        File.lchown st.uid, st.gid, path
      rescue NotImplementedError
      end
    else
      File.chown st.uid, st.gid, path
    end
  rescue Errno::EPERM
    # clear setuid/setgid
    ... omitted ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Docs aren't complete, so it's a little confusing. Actually the Docs above the `copy_entry` method can apply to the `copy_metadata` method.